# java (generics?) class with c++ like type traits

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

I'm new to java. Is there a way to write generic java classes, like those using type traits in C++? 
For example, one can write in c++ `template<class C> class foo;`, where `C` contains a list of specifications -- static constants and classes used in the generic declarations, which can be used to, e.g. initialize size of a static array.

In particular, I'm trying to generalize a set of classes (around 3000 lines of code) to operate on `EnumSet<EnumA>` and `EnumSet<EnumB>`, where the first is a subset of `EnumA`, and later is a subset of `EnumB`. There are probably around 5 combinations that I need. As a "brute" method, I can of course instantiate several "trait objects" to hold different subsets, and pass such instance through those call stack, but wonder if there's a cleaner/compile-time method. A problem I ran into with generic is that it complains that the generic parameter can't be used in static context.

Comment: this link described you how to do it https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: *Short Answer*: No. *Longer Answer*: Noooo. *Explanation*: Java is not C++, and Java generics are a language extension that provides type-safety at compile time (at run-time they are erased<sup><sub>except for one type-cast</sub></sup>). Java does have a much richer run-time capability in the form of reflection. Java 8+ does have default methods in interfaces (which may be what you are looking for).

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch. Is passing a trait struct through the call stack a good practice, or is it common practice like refactoring out a mediator etc

Comment: @Bayo In what context? Since Java doesn't have traits or structs I assume you mean in C++, but you didn't post code ... so I have no idea what you mean by *passing a trait struct through the call stack*.